# Suddenly no windows, no taskbar no right clicks on Kubuntu 17.04 on Virtual Box 5.1.22

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu

For no apparent reason when I started Kubuntu on Vbox today I had no taskbar, no right-click, and no left click on the desktop. When I hover the mouse over where the taskbar used to be I can see a preview of the currently running programs, but when I click on the program (or on any program from the start menu) it will not open. First I thought the mouse clicks weren't being registered, but I was able to click on the shut down menu, though when I try to shut down the system I get a black screen and nothing happens, so I just have to close the window of the guest OS. The simplest thing would be to delete the guest and install it again, but I'm just curious what the problem might be... and even more curious how could I solve it when I can't use terminal or any other program since I can't open any windows...

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue. It happened to me after I enabled 3D acceleration and increased the Base Memory. After multiple reboots, finally my KWin crashed.

Fix: Restart kwin, shutdown, Remove 3d acceleration

Comment: I'll try that next time. For now I just reinstalled it. BTW: The same thing happened to a Lubuntu guest - same fix - reinstalled.